# PHP - How can i adapt my JQuery Menu to my PHP menu

Tags: php

I want to adapt my Jquery menu code, to my php Menu, that recives values from the database.

I want to create a menu with submenus. And when the person watching the website clicks at the separator, it shows all submenus from the database

JQuery menu

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<ul id="menu"> 
<li id="Item1">

<a href="#" onclick="show()">Separador 1</a>
<ul id="submenu">
<a href="#"> Submenu 1 </a>
<br>
<a href="#"> Submenu 2 </a>
<br>
<a href="#"> Submenu 3 </a>
 </ul>
</li>

<li id="Item2" >Separador 2</li>

<li id="Item3">Separador 3</li>
</ul>

<style>
#menu{

}

li{
float:left;
display:inline;
margin-left: 10px;
}

ul #submenu{
display:none;
margin-left: -40px;
}
</style>

<script>
function show() {
    $('#submenu').toggle();

  }

</script>
```

Menu PHP

```
<?php
    function menu($url,$name){
        echo "<br><br><li><a href='$url'>$name</a></li> ";
    }
?>
<?php
    function submenu($suburl,$subname){
        echo "<ul><li><a href='$suburl'>$subname</a></li></ul>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You should make ajax call, which returns your information and then parse it and append to body !! Just in the whole, but I thinkg you'll find out how to use jquery !

Comment: Yea, but what about the submenus?

Comment: You will get like add class for menu and then in jquery 
`<a href="#" class="click">`
     `$('.click').click(function(){ 
      at first you should get post data and then make html with it
      .post{}..
      $.each(post_data) {
         var html = '<li>'+post_data.text+'</li>';
         $(this).append(html);
        }
     });`

Something like that!! :)